# Access - Comparision Between Null and Numeric Value

Tags: ms-access

I am testing out a make-table where I assume some numbers are being compared to null (my mistake). I am curious however, as what you would expect is not returned.

IE `iif( 5 > null, 'Yes', 'No')`

```
iif( 5 < null, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Both return No, at least for me. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Null means "No value" so it cannot be compared.

Comment: your comment answers my question best, but there is a follow up question. If nulls can not be compared, why then does the iif return a value rather than null

Comment: You cannot compare a Null value to a literal value e.g. 5. The `IsNull()` function does not compare, but checks is the value is null and returns True or False.

Comment: The `IIF` function will check the *condition* and return True or False (or whatever is placed in the True/False parts. `IIF([condition],[True],[False])`. In your case, 5 cannot be compared to Null so it returns False ('No').

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
IIf([some field] Is Null, 'No', 'Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect something to be null, always check whether it is null or not using IsNull and then proceed with comparison. You can also replace the null value with value of your choice using Nz() function. Thanks